# can't get for loop loop's count to output it's entire index to html element

Tags: javascript, html

I am simply trying to get my loop's counter to output all of its indexes to my html

Here is my html inputs:

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <label for="start">Start</label>
    <input type="number" name="start">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="end">End</label>
    <input type="number" name="end">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="step">Step</label>
    <input type="number" name="step">
  </div>
  <p id="myP"></p>
```

Here is my javaScript:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var start = document.getElementByName("start")[0].value;
  var end = document.getElementByName("end")[0].value;
  var step = document.getElementByName("step")[0].value;

  for (var i = start; i < end; i += step) {
    document.getElementById("myP").value = i;

  }
}
```

if start(4), end(20), and step(3) and I console.log in chrome devTool the output is 4, 10, 16 so I pretty sure the function works but for days I have been able to figure out how to get my desired result to my html.

Comment: document.getElementById("myP").textContext= i;

Comment: @ILikeToMoveItMoveIt thanks

Answer (score 0):

That paragraph doesnt have a value attribute. You need to set its textContext.

```
 function myFunction(){
         var start = document.getElementByName("start")[0].value;
         var end = document.getElementByName("end")[0].value;
         var step = document.getElementByName("step")[0].value;

         for(var i = start; i < end; i += step){
          document.getElementById("myP").textContext= i;

          }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of issues:

- You need to convert the input values to integers using the `parseInt` function
- There is no `document.getElementByName`, but rather `document.getElementsByName`
- I added an array to collect each value for `i` then set the concatenation of all collected values to the `innerHTML` property of `myP`

```js
function myFunction(){
    var start = parseInt(document.getElementsByName("start")[0].value);
    var end = parseInt(document.getElementsByName("end")[0].value);
    var step = parseInt(document.getElementsByName("step")[0].value);

    var is = [];
    for(var i = start; i < end; i += step){
        is.push(i);
    }
    document.getElementById("myP").innerHTML = is.join();
}

myFunction();
```

```html
<div>
    <label for="start">Start</label>
    <input type="number" name="start" value="4">
</div>
<div>
    <label for="end">End</label>
    <input type="number" name="end" value="20">
</div>
<div>
     <label for="step">Step</label>
     <input type="number" name="step" value="6">
</div>
<p id="myP"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

use innerHTML.

```
for(var i = start; i < end; i += step){
  document.getElementById("myP").innerHTML = i;
}
```